# Getting nested struct

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have the following structs:

```golang
type Users struct {
    ID           int64            `gorm:"id" json:"id"`
    Name         int64            `gorm:"name" json:"name"`
    UserTypeID   int              `gorm:"column:user_type_id" json:"-"`
    UserType     BusinnesUserType `gorm:"foreignKey:id;references:user_type_id" json:"user_type"`
    LanguageID   int64            `gorm:"column:language_id" json:"-"`
    Language     Language         `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:LanguageID" json:"language"`
}
```

```golang
type BusinnesUserType struct {
    ID          int64           `gorm:"id" json:"id"`
    Description json.RawMessage `gorm:"description" json:"description"`
}
```

```golang
type Language struct {
    ID          int64           `gorm:"id" json:"id"`
    Description json.RawMessage `gorm:"description" json:"description"`
}
```

I'm trying to get something like:

```json
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"dd",
   "user_type":{
      "id":1,
      "description":{
         "en":"admin"
      }
   },
   "language":{
      "id":1,
      "description":{
         "en":"English"
      }
   }
}
```

And this is my gorm query with mysql:

```golang
db.Preload("UserType").Preload("Language").Where("id=?",1).Find(&user)
```

If I use the Debug() option I see:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `languages` WHERE `languages`.`id` = 1
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM `business_user_types` WHERE `business_user_types`.`id` = 1
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = 1
```

But I get the following json instead:

```json
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"dd",
   "user_type":{
      "id":null,
      "description":null
   },
   "language":{
      "id":null,
      "description":null
   }
}
```

I'm using the preload command in a wrong way? I already tried with Joins and Association, same result.

Comment: do all of the executed queries return results (when queries are printed out, the number of rows is printed as well)?

Comment: hi @EminLaletovic, yes, everything is working well, also, I have an endpoint per every query and they return the corresponding data, but when I try with the nested struct no

Comment: What type do the description database fields for `BusinessUserType` and `Language` have? You've declared them `json.RawMessage` suggesting they are JSON/JSONB fields.

Comment: I'm usgin mariadb and as the documentation said, the json field is the same like any string:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/
I'm using rigth now longtext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution. The problem was in the "preload" function, because need the relationship with the preloaded table.
Now, my gorm query is this one:

```golang
result := db.Preload("UserType", "id=?", &user.UserTypeID).
        Preload("Language", "id=?", &user.LanguageID).
        Where("business_users.id=?", 1).Find(&user)
```

And my struct is like this:

```golang
type BusinessUsers struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name           string `gorm:"name" json:"name"`
    UserTypeID     int64
    UserType       BusinessUserType `gorm:"foreignkey:UserTypeID"`
    LanguageID     int64
    Language       Language `gorm:"foreignkey:LanguageID"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- I think Users model should look like this ..

```
type Users struct {
    ID           int64            `gorm:"id" json:"id"`
    Name         int64            `gorm:"name" json:"name"`
    UserTypeID   int              `gorm:"column:user_type_id" json:"-"`
    UserType     BusinnesUserType `gorm:"foreignKey:UserTypeID;" json:"user_type"` // changed this line
    LanguageID   int64            `gorm:"column:language_id" json:"-"`
    Language     Language         `gorm:"foreignKey:LanguageID;" json:"language"` // changed this line
}
```

- changed this lines ..

```
Language     Language         `gorm:"foreignKey:LanguageID;" json:"language"`

UserType     BusinnesUserType `gorm:"foreignKey:UserTypeID;" json:"user_type"`
```

- **Edit** you have to ForeignKey Manually also

```
// User : Relations
DB.Model(&models.Users{}).AddForeignKey("user_type_id", "Businnesusertypes(id)", "<CASCADE/RESTRICT>", "<CASCADE/RESTRICT>")
DB.Model(&models.Users{}).AddForeignKey("language_id", "languages(id)", "<CASCADE/RESTRICT>", "<CASCADE/RESTRICT>")
```

Comment: Hi same result, it's not working... I change the reference to the name of my variable on the struct

Comment: hi, @cervantesj, EDITED Answer hope it will resolve your issue

Comment: Can not make the relation and returns 0 results. I got the following error:

```invalid field found for struct Users field UserType, need to define a foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface```

Comment: Hi, That was my first configuration to gorm (without the reference field)... Not working either, i just got the same result like my post, "null" and "null" for id and description

Comment: Hi @M_x thank you for your post, however, I can not insert the AddForeignKey tag in the function, because said is not part of the function xD I'm using Gorm V2, I don't know  if before this functionalitty was able to do it or not. I'm still at the same point

Comment: Gorm V2 takes care of foreign keys on its own when you AutoMigrate. Have you tried just removing the foreignKey tag entirely? Gorm should be able to pick up the right foreign key name from the name of your relation since you're following the standard naming pattern for a [Belongs-To relationship](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Belongs-To).